# Magento grid view show out of stock banner/label

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

So I have looked for this online and nothing worked.

I want a banner/label to show on my category view (in grid mode) that a certain product is out of stuck.

I tried to add:

```
$stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product);
$qty = $stock->getQty();
if($qty <= 0)
{
<span class="out-of-stock"><span>Sold Out</span></span>
}
```

literally after the `foreach product` in the grid mode but didn't work

Any help?

---

**EDIT2**

[Out of stock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYY7F.png)

[List VIew](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eu40j.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to tried following code in your category list.phtml file:-

```
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <span class="in-stock"><span>In Stock</span></span>
 <?php else: ?>
    <span class="out-of-stock"><span>Sold Out</span></span>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174033/discussion-on-answer-by-raj-magento-grid-view-show-out-of-stock-banner-label).

Comment: Sorry. And hey Raj, any ideas?

Comment: Hi. Let's talk in chat.